# Suggest resources on advance data structures

Tags: data-structures

Please suggest me any resource (video lecture or book or website) for learning advance data structure topics. More precisely: Binary index trees, Segment trees, Suffix trees, Dictionaries, Hash Maps, Rope, Tries, etc. If it has sample problems asked frequently in programming competitions based on these concept then its a plus.

PS: I tried some earlier posts on the same topic but they din't serve my query, so I had to make a fresh post. Precisely I don't want basic data structure topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to find it all is Internet. Just keep searching and you would find some nice stuffs on each topic.
Here is where you can find a help on suffix tree/array:

http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~gusfield/cs224f09/

Segment Trees:

http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor#Segment_Trees

Binary Index Trees:

http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees

If I find something good on other topics too, I'd edit my post and add them.
Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks...  It's interesting. It really helped me on suffix trees. Looking for more... :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you tackle [The Art of Computer Programming](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: I have. Thanks anyway. But that doesn't give me what I need (Binary Index Trees, Segment Trees, Suffix Trees etc).

Answer (score 0):

I think data-structures and algorithm are linked together.
So I recommend 'Introduction to Algorithms'
If you think this book is too heavy... 'Data-structures in C'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But as I have mentioned I don't want such general Algorithm book. I have already gone through that. Help me precisely on the specified topic. Not on general algorithms. I have see "Introduction to algorithms". I have seen "The art of Computer Programming". But didn't find Binary Index trees, segment trees, suffix trees etc. :(

Comment: Yes, I suggest you search for the topics one by one on the internet. Or ask your friends who are attending the acm contest.

Comment: ummm...   yeah, that is the only way out now I see.